# Resources to help me with Java programming?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, resources

I am a beginner Java developer and although I tried searching I have yet to find any good books for learning java programming. I am good enough at the basics that I don't need a 'for dummies' book, but I was wondering if anyone has seen a really useful/well written book/website about Java programming. Specifically I would like things to do with GUI or Server/Client communication or Java coding tips.

If this question has already been asked I am sorry, I tried searching but couldn't find what I wanted... Please give me a link to the question instead of downvoting! Thanks

Comment: If you're interested in GUI books, take a look at [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/).  While you may consider it "basic", I still refer to it from time, even after 14 years.  [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), you can also take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more advance graphics APIs

Comment: For java coding tips, i recommend "Effective Java". http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Programming-Language-Guide-ebook/dp/B000OZ0N5I/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1380172214&sr=8-2&keywords=Effective+java

This is very nicely written book to tell you some insights of java.

Comment: Effective Java is an excellent, although slightly more advanced, book.

Comment: I used Java in a Nutshell and it's a great book. There's a small chapter in there for Java networking, and although I haven't read it, I've heard good things about `Java Network Programming` Elliotte Rusty Harold. On the other hand, I think you don't really need a book to learn about Swing... there are A LOT of resources and tutorials online and books can never offer the exact information you will need (I think).